# How do I create a pyside2 QScrollArea only occupy half the QWidget

Tags: python, pyside2, qscrollarea

I'm trying to make it so that my Window isn't completely occupied by a single QScrollArea.

[image: Here is where I want to put another widget]

Basically, I have a Scroll Area, and I want to add something next to it.

I've already seen it created in PySimpleGUI, so I'm sure it can also be created in PySide2, but I'm having trouble creating it. This is where I found the code for the PySimpleGUI.
[How can I create a column that is scrollable in PySimpleGUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69321890/how-can-i-create-a-column-that-is-scrollable-in-pysimplegui)

[image: Scroll Area and Static Area in the same window]

So far, I've tried to put the QScrollArea and the QVLayoutBox into a QHLayoutBox, with the addLayout() method, which I thought would allow me to put more widgets next to the QScrollArea, but this just gave me the following error.

```
self.scroll = QScrollArea()
self.hbox = QHBoxLayout()
self.widget = QWidget()
self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()
self.hbox.addLayout(self.vbox)


RuntimeError: QWidget::setLayout: Attempting to set QLayout "" on QWidget "", when the QLayout already has a parent
```

I've tried searching it on GitHub for some examples, but everything I found was just people expanding their QScrollArea, and not limiting the Scroll Area to a certain part of the window.

Here is a small piece of code I found online that shows the scroll area, with the code that produces my error added in.

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QSlider, QLineEdit, QLabel, QPushButton, QScrollArea,QApplication,
                             QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QMainWindow)
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt
from PySide2 import QtWidgets
import sys


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.hbox = QHBoxLayout() # remove this line for the code to work
        self.scroll = QScrollArea()
        self.widget = QWidget()
        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.hbox.addLayout(self.vbox) # also this line

        for i in range(1,50):
            object = QLabel("TextLabel")
            self.vbox.addWidget(object)

        self.widget.setLayout(self.vbox)

        self.scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scroll.setWidget(self.widget)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.scroll)

        self.setGeometry(600, 100, 1000, 900)
        self.setWindowTitle('Scroll Area Demonstration')
        self.show()

        return

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Without the lines I added in, a scrollbox is created, however, it takes up the entire window, which isn't what I'm trying to create.

Comment: You can add more widgets to your layout, and the space will be divided between them, but until you actually add other widgets, the scrollarea will take up all the space it has.

Comment: First you're adding vbox to hbox. That makes hbox the parent of vbox. Then you're setting vbox as the layout for widget. That would make widget its parent but that's not possible because hbox is already the parent. If you want nested layouts in a widget, you should set the top level layout on the widget.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what a top level layout is. I searched it up and it says hbox, vbox and some other layouts were top level layouts but I'm not sure how it applies here.  Do you mean I should make hbox the layout in the init function to make it a top level layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misunderstanding the usage of layout managers in Qt.

A layout doesn't do anything on its own, nor it is a overall structure that manages everything: it has to be set on a widget and then it will allow to manage the *children* of that widget, so it must be created and set within the structure of the widget tree (parent/child relations).

The general structure is this:

- QWidget (the parent);

  - QLayout;

    - one or more QWidgets (the children);
    - one or more QLayouts, which in turn should contain further widgets and/or layouts;

The assumption is that a layout only makes sense when set *on* a widget, in order to manage *at least* a child widget.

In your case, you are also using a QMainWindow, which *requires* using a "central widget" containing the central part of the window along with other elements (menu bar, status bar, dock widgets and tool bars). QMainWindow has its own *private* layout, required to manage the above elements, so if you want to show more than one widget in its center, you need a *container* widget, set a layout for it, and add the real widgets to it.

The structure you want can be created like this (I'm adding some labels to the scroll area to follow your example image):

[image: Image of the layout structure]

The solid lines represent actual QWidgets, while the dashed ones are used for layout managers. Note that QMainWindow has its own internal layout as mentioned above, whereas layouts set on a widget use the same color.

- QMainWindow (purple);

  - QWidget (black): the *central widget*, used as container;

    - QHBoxLayout, to horizontally show the scroll area and the rest, containing:

      1. QScrollArea (green);

         - QWidget (orange), the container for the widgets that will be scrolled;

           - QVBoxLayout, for the scroll area contents;

             - some QLabels (dark yellow);
      2. QVBoxLayout (blue), note that this is a *nested* layout;

         - the QLabels (steel blue) that will be shown on the side;

```py
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        central = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central)

        mainLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        central.setLayout(mainLayout)
        # alternatively, you can directly install the layout when creating it
        # hbox = QHBoxLayout(central)

        self.scroll = QScrollArea()
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.scroll)

        self.scrollContent = QWidget()
        scrollLayout = QVBoxLayout(self.scrollContent)
        for i in range(1, 51):
            scrollLayout.addWidget(QLabel("Scroll label {}".format(i)))

        self.scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scroll.setWidget(self.scrollContent)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addLayout(vbox)

        for i in range(1, 11):
            vbox.addWidget(QLabel("Normal label {}".format(i)))
```

Further notes:

- `object` is an important Python keyword, and you shall not use it as a variable name;
- avoid setting a geometry for the window, as you cannot know the screen sizes and layout other users have; you can eventually call `self.resize()` (or eventually implement [`sizeHint()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#sizeHint-prop)), but you should not use arbitrary and hardcoded values for any of that; at the very least, you should compute a possible geometry through [`QApplication.primaryScreen()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#primaryScreen-prop);
- it's good practice to *not* call `show()` in the `__init__` of a window, as that should only be done externally *after* the window has been initialized;
- `return` at the end of a function is implicit in Python;

Comment: Oh thanks for the lesson!! So in this case, instead of using QVBox as the child under QHBox, the QScrollArea is the child, and that QScrollArea is the parent of the QVBox. So I will need to use QHBox.addWidget(QScrollArea) to get the scroll area onto the Horizontal Layout?

Comment: @BigBrainProductions Not exactly. The QScrollArea is the parent of the *widget* that will be actually scrolled, which has its own layout (the `scrollLayout` QVBoxLayout); then, yes, you shall add the scroll area to the horizontal layout. I updated the answer with an image that should clarify the whole structure.